# Algorithm to find intersection of two convex polyhedrones

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

In geometry, a polyhedron is a three-dimensional shape with flat polygonal faces, straight edges, and sharp corners or vertices.

I have two convex polyhedrons which intersect with each other. The intersection part of these two polyhedrons is my desire space.

I want to know is there any algorithm that finds this space appropriately? If available, is the code was (open source) written for it?

Comment: There are a few algorithms for this. You'll find plenty of papers describing solutions to this problem. If you want to find an implementation you'll have to specify the used language though. And even then you'll probably be out of luck and will have to do considerable work on your own.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution for this would be the following:
A convex polyhedron can be described as the intersection of the half-planes defined by the individual faces of the polyhedron (probably easier to think of this in 2D, but it works just the same way in 3D).

With this definition, finding the intersection is as simple as taking the intersection of the half-planes of both polyhedra. Since this is a rather primitive operation, pretty much any computational-geometry library should support it.

Comment: My main goal from this question is to find a way for "polyhedrons clipping". Are your solution leads to polyhedrons clipping? Are you find any source code for polyhedrons clipping?

Comment: @NULL it calculates the intersection of two polyhedra. What you do with that result is entirely another story. You should've stated precisely what you want in the question. It's a bit late for that now though, so you'll have to ask another question - please don't just edit this question. As for source-code: asking for offsite-resources is offtopic here and the same issues I've already mentioned in my comment to your question apply even more for polyhedron-clipping.

Comment: if your polyhedrones are convex, they are equal to their convex hull so you can use a convex hull algorithm (like there exist plenty) to find the intersection you need.